# mod_rewrite is not working for following url with special characters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a url coming from SAP EP to Apache. I am trying to rewrite some url using mod_rewrite, but unfortunately for following url it is not working:

https://dsssloc.ril.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.xmlformpreview?XMLFormID=SAP_SRM_Announcements&edit/test=/documents/SRM/SRM%20Messages/409af2e3-ef17-2e10-5da9-f0a7512cdfc7.xml

Code in httpd.conf is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^XMLFormID=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule "^/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot.*$" https://mydssa.ril.com/irj/portal/srm/invalid [L]
```

Please help me.

Regards,
Jayendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. I think the only problem with your version is the "/" at the beginning of the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^XMLFormID=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot.*$ https://mydssa.ril.com/irj/portal/srm/invalid [L]
```